# How can I fill and get the PDF output of a Excel spreadsheet programmatically?

Tags: .net, excel, vba, automation, ole

I have a Excel workbook that allows me to input the values of some fields, click on a button, and then a PDF report it's generated based on my input. I then have to choose the directory where to save this PDF file.

I have to create an REST-like API that will receive a payload with the input parameters for the Excel worksheet, and return the generated PDF file.

It isn't possible for me to have access to the macros, data and logic inside of the Workbook, so I can't just implement the same logic directly in my API. The Workbook will also change periodically (formulas, macros, etc), and the only thing that will remain is the input fields and the PDF output.

After some tests with [this library](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi), I'm not sure if it allows me to call a button (to generate the PDF) and specify the output directory. I mainly use C# and .NET, how can I achieve this?

Comment: If only Excel can compute what you want, then you need to find a way to automate Excel server-side, which poses technical (and licensing) issues : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office. Or use the new Excel REST (Graph) API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/excel-concept-overview  not sure you can export a PDF with this though...

Comment: Npoi works directly with the files but it cannot generate pdf. EPPlus the same. There are free libraries (also commercial ones) that perform such a task.
In my opinion the best way is to write directly the pdf file (i.e. using iTextSharp). It is a little bit more complex but you have full control of the output and  you don't need to have other dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Excel Interop library? You can get it through Nuget by installing the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` package.

That will allow you to open up the workbook, write some values into some cells, and run the macro which is called by the button.

```
// Start a new instance of Excel
var app = new Interop.Application();

// Open the workbook 
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path);

// Set some values
workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Range["A1"].Value2 = 123;

// Run the macro
app.Run("Module1.MyMacro");
```

There are some limitations to this though. The computer which you run this on must have Excel installed, since the Interop library is literally opening Excel. Also, the `Application.Run` method will return instantly, before the macro has actually finished running. You could possibly get around this by continually checking for the PDF output file to appear:

```
while (!File.Exists(path))
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait for 5 seconds
}
```